# Move players inventories to another server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I have 2 minecraft servers with 2 different hosts. I want to transfer players data (including their inventory) from server1 to server2. Is it possible? I will also be moving the world to server2, but will chests keep their items?

Comment: Copying the `playerdata` directory within your world save should get you the player's data, including their inventories. However, keep in mind that this will also include their location, which might be bad for their in-game health if the worlds are different across the servers. If you also want achievements and other stats, you can also copy the `stats` directory.

Answer (score 1):

When you move the world data and the player data to the new server everything will be just as it was.

I have moved server at least a dozen times. If you move everything at one time you should be fine. If you move the data separate you may run into issues.

The player data files should be under the same directory as your world data. Just copy everything together.